# Evaluate the title is correct in the view (rendered)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

data is displayed in the view and it needs to be validated ....

Comment: 1. Go read a tutorial on RSpec. 2. Write the code.

Answer (score 1):

I would write something like this

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe 'Value integration', :type => :request do

  it 'returns the correct number of items' do
    get 'value.json'

    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to have(2).items
  end
end
```

Note that is a [request spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/request-specs/request-spec), a [controller spec](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-5/docs/controller-specs) might be a better choice, but I wouldn't be able to write the whole file for you without knowning some internals about your controller.

Comment: I’m wondering, why would you write the code for impudent strangers for free?

Comment: @john: Seems like I missed to tell you that request spec belong into the `spec/requests` folder, not into the `spec/controllers` folder. Or you might want to post your controller and we can write a proper controller spec together...

Comment: @mudasobwa: I enjoy the recreational effect of writing simple code snippets.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that is well-known-to-me effect :) Anyway, I upvoted for the sake of showing I appreciate the effort.